# sql query to count the rows

Tags: sql

i have a table like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEoJR.png)

Comment: Looks like a college/university assignment.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: You did absolutely noting to solve this problem, as far as we can see. You did not even cut the screenshot properly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort at all

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    base.*, aaa.the_count
FROM
    TABLE base
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        GROUP,
        count(*) AS the_count
    FROM
        TABLE
    GROUP BY
        1
) aaa ON aaa. GROUP = base. GROUP
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

this will return you number of records in a table:

```
select count(*) from tablename;
```